# PHP update via textboxes

Tags: php, sql-update

Right now the update only works if all textboxes are filled out, so the user can't just update productName for example. There isn't an error, but if the other textboxes are left blank then the database is updated with blanks and 0's. I want this to update whatever textboxes receive input, be it one or all, and leave the rest of the info alone if nothing is entered.

If productName for that row is Samsung, description is 'A phone' wholesalePrice is 179.99    and I just update the productName textbox only I still want the description and wholesalePrice to stay the same. Right now if I just update the productName only then the wholesalePrice shows as 0.00 and the description is blank. I tried using OR statements rather than commas in the query and whatever textbox I entered info in returned a 0.

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    try {
        $query = "UPDATE products SET productName = :productName, description = :description, wholesalePrice = :wholesalePrice,
    retailPrice = :retailPrice, category = :category, quantityOnHand = :quantityOnHand
    WHERE productID = :productID";
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':productID', $_POST['id']);
        $statement->bindValue(':productName', $productName);
        $statement->bindValue(':description', $description);
        $statement->bindValue(':wholesalePrice', $wholesalePrice);
        $statement->bindValue(':retailPrice', $retailPrice);
        $statement->bindValue(':category', $category);
        $statement->bindValue(':quantityOnHand', $quantityOnHand);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->closeCursor();

//reload page after data is entered into the table and display a message if successful for 3 seconds before redirect
        $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] );
        exit;
```

Comment: Only update the columns if the value is not empty [MySQL update column only if value not empty where](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857895/mysql-update-column-only-if-value-not-empty-where)

Comment: How would that work with the binds?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a helper array for your columns to bind values dynamically if each `$_POST` value is set. Then you can create the update query for only those values.

```
$fields = array('productName', 'description', 'wholesalePrice', 'retailPrice', 'category', 'quantityOnHand');
$values = array();
$binds = array();

foreach($fields as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($_POST[$value])) {
        $values[] = $value.' = :'.$value;
        $binds[':'.$value] = $_POST[$value];
    }
}

if (!empty($values)) {
    $query = "UPDATE products SET ";
    $query .= implode(', ', $values);
    $query .= " WHERE productID = :productID";
    $binds[':productID'] = $_POST['id'];
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute($binds);
    $statement->closeCursor();
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you have the values stored in variables then you can use variable variables:

```
foreach($fields as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($$value)) {
        $values[] = $value.' = :'.$value;
        $binds[':'.$value] = $$value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work. The textboxes are filled out on another page. search.php -> update.php -> updateFunct.php -> update.php
The data is obtained on search.php and it takes that specific row's data through the update link to the update.php page. The updateFunct.php handles the processing.

Comment: Then you can use variable variables. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass all existing values to form fields so existing data is passed to the sql update if nothing changes. On submit validate the data, then do the update.

```
<textarea name="description">'.$row['description'].'</textarea>

if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
  $productname = $_POST['productname'];
  $description = $_POST['description'];
  // etc ....
  try {
    // sql
  }catch{
    // error
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to specify WHAT you're trying to catch. You can't just put `catch{}` and expect it to work. http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#language.exceptions.catch

Comment: The form is on a separate page. update.php contains the textboxes and updateFunct.php has the above code. The way the page works, a user can enter something into a search box like "Samsung" and the database lists all the info about every available Samsung found along with an update and delete button next to each row. When update is clicked it goes to the update form on which half displays the current info and the other half of the page allows input for updating. Once submit is clicked it updates and refreshes with the new input shown on the disabled half of the page.

Comment: The catch statement I have isn't the problem. It catches and handles errors. Nothing more.

Comment: My example is basic. It isn't meant to be a copy paste solution and anyone working with exceptions understands you need to catch the (Exception $e).

@Kr4ckl3s
You need to pass those fields on the form regardless. Never have any empty form field if data already exists. A user may think they can merely add to the existing via the blank form and or retype the whole thing.