# Update only columns with a set value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been searching for a solution but didn't find a simple solution. For example this link talks about this but didn't help me much: [MySQL update column only if value not empty where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857895/mysql-update-column-only-if-value-not-empty-where)

Here is what I would like to achieve:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE table_name SET field1 = :value1, field2 = :value2 WHERE id = :id");

$stmt->bindValue(':value1', $value1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
if(!empty($value2)) $stmt->bindValue(':value2', $value2, PDO::PARAM_STR); // if the field was present in the form, otherwise IGNORE it
$stmt->bindValue(':key', $key, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

I've seen some solutions with COALESCE but it works only will null values.

Comment: your questions isn't clear

Comment: Thanks guys for your replies. Actually it's not about executing the whole update if value2 is not empty. it can be empty because cleared by the client! in other words, I only want to update the fields that were displayed in the form..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check what data should be updated and when generate for such fields update SQL statement.

1. Select data WHERE id = :id
2. Check if need to update some fields.
3. Generate and execute update for such fields only.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, could you plz explain more in details?

Comment: I'm sorry if my answer wasn't clear. I mean: why should we update data if the same version is already in database record? Generally I'm getting all data from db by id. Then I'm checking if new data is not the same as data currently stored in db. Then I'm generating udate query for fields changed & executing it.

Comment: Personally I don't check if new data is not empty or null. I'm generating update query if something has changed only.

Comment: I see, but here is the problem: lets say in the 1st form, there are "first name", "last name", "email" and "telephone", when you run an update, you will update all the 4 fields. But sometime i can have a 2nd form with only "first name" and "last name", without "telephone", if I run an update withh all fields, the telephone value will be removed. So that why i would like to have a mysql query that uses only specific fields

Comment: While searching on internet a solution, i find my own post that hasn't been solved yet!! :/ any one has got a solution??? I found this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131873/update-only-changed-columns-with-mysql-prepared-statements is it the best solution?? Thanks