# Update one or more field ignoring empty field in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to update one or more field ignoring the empty fields in MySQL and PHP?

These are values that I need to enter in a HTML form:

```
<input type='text' placeholder='ID' name='ID' value='' id='ID'>
<input type='text' placeholder='Product name' name='prod_name' value=''>
<input type='text' placeholder='Description' name='prod_desc' value=''>
<input type='text' placeholder='Solde price' name='prod_s_price' value=''>
<input type='text' placeholder='Reg. price' name='prod_r_price' value=''>
<input type='text' placeholder='Product model' name='prod_mod' value=''>
```

When I submit the values, they are stored in those variables:

```
$prod_id = $_POST['ID']; //Int ID
$prod_name = $_POST['prod_name']; //String
$prod_desc = $_POST["prod_desc"]; //String
$prod_s_price = $_POST["prod_s_price"]; //Float
$prod_r_price = $_POST["prod_r_price"]; //Float
$prod_mod = $_POST["prod_mod"]; //String
```

When we send the POST request, it goes in a MySQL query:

```
if ($_POST['ID'] == null) {
    header('Location: ../index.php?update=error_undefined');
} else {

    $sql = "UPDATE app SET app_name='$prod_name', app_desc='$prod_desc', app_s_price=$prod_s_price, app_r_price=$prod_r_price, app_mod='$prod_mod' WHERE app_id=$prod_id;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    header('Location: ../index.php?update=succes');
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857895/mysql-update-column-only-if-value-not-empty-where

Comment: This question is too old

Comment: okay, it's old but does it answer your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the following, it will not arise any sort of issue.

```
if ($_POST['ID'] == null) {
    header('Location: ../index.php?update=error_undefined');
} else {
    $update_any = false;
    $sql = "UPDATE app SET ";
    $prod1 = null;
    if (!empty($prod_name)) {
        $prod1 = "app_name='$prod_name', ";
        $update_any = true;
    }
    $prod2 = null;
    if (!empty($prod_desc)) {
        $prod2 = "app_desc='$prod_desc', ";
        $update_any = true;
    }
    $prod3 = null;
    if (!empty($prod_s_price)) {
        $prod3 = "app_s_price='$prod_s_price', ";
        $update_any = true;
    }
    $prod4 = null;
    if (!empty($prod_r_price)) {
        $prod4 = "app_r_price='$prod_r_price', ";
        $update_any = true;
    }
    $prod5 = null;
    if (!empty($prod_mod)) {
        $prod5 = "app_mod='$prod_mod', ";
        $update_any = true;
    }

    $notrimed_query = $prod1.$prod2.$prod3.$prod4.$prod5;
    $trimed_query = rtrim($notrimed_query, ", ");

    $query =  $sql.$trimed_query." WHERE app_id=$prod_id;";

    if ($update_any)
    {
        mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        header('Location: ../index.php?update=succes');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No Update Occur.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Work juste fine that way! Just need to replace the PHP code to that! Thanks to me.

```
if ($_POST['ID'] == null) {
    header('Location: ../index.php?update=error_undefined');
} else {
    $sql = "UPDATE app SET ";
    $prod1 = null;
    if (!empty($prod_name)) {
        $prod1 = "app_name='$prod_name', ";
    }
    $prod2 = null;
    if (!empty($prod_desc)) {
        $prod2 = "app_desc='$prod_desc', ";
    }
    $prod3 = null;
    if (!empty($prod_s_price)) {
        $prod3 = "app_s_price='$prod_s_price', ";
    }
    $prod4 = null;
    if (!empty($prod_r_price)) {
        $prod4 = "app_r_price='$prod_r_price', ";
    }
    $prod5 = null;
    if (!empty($prod_mod)) {
        $prod5 = "app_mod='$prod_mod', ";
    }

    $notrimed_query = $prod1.$prod2.$prod3.$prod4.$prod5;
    $trimed_query = rtrim($notrimed_query, ", ");

    $query =  $sql.$trimed_query." WHERE app_id=$prod_id;";
    
    mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    header('Location: ../index.php?update=succes');
}
```

Comment: No in this way if no field will be entered then error will be generated.